# Let custom module access private files via file_get_contents

Tags: files

I have a custom module (Drupal 7) where I want to read the contents of a file using file_get_contents($file) in the private directory. Theres a access denied error, as the module accesses as anonymous.

I can access the file via browser via the url created with file_create_url(), but gain no access from my module.

Is there a way to grant my module the permission to open files?
Any other ideas are welcome, too.

Thanks, Marc

Comment: If the file's on the same server use the file system path rather than the url

Comment: Thank you, @Clive. That solved it. PS: It seems like you can't dpm() the result of file_get_content, need to encode that first. That added to my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

"Use the file system path rather than the url" - Thanks @Clive, this is the solution.